# focus() causes page to scroll up when clicked on editor in draft-js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am using draft-js for text editor, whenever I call .focus() on text editor click, it scrolls the page to top.

```
this.refs.editor.focus();
```

The page scrolls up when clicked on editor both in chrome and firefox. Updated the version of fbjs to : ">=0.8.15" as suggested in
[click here](https://github.com/flarnie/draft-js/commit/c07892e5e60c6881a7743592734b1fcecbc8ddf7).draft js version is : "^0.10.5".Problem was also raised sometime ago [click here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/1381).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve if you dont want the window to focus to your input?